# My suggested edit was denied, however the reasoning makes no sense

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I made a suggested edit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11455621), but it was denied with the following reason.

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

In the context of the edit, This does not entirely make sense. In no way did I intend for it to be a 'message to the author' or to 'address the author' in any way.

The edit was a simple one, just to change git in the post to use https rather than ssh, seeiing as that unless you have ssh keys set up with the machine and github that you are cloning from, it fails with permission denied.

From personal experience, I have never setup ssh keys with github for a *production server* (it only needs to pull changes), and seeing this question could quite possibly be in regards to a production environment, I do not understand why this 'addresses the author'. I do realize I could just add it as a comment, but why "duct tape" the question rather than fixing it properly?

Comment: I probably would have approved that, but I know enough about Git to verify that your edit is correct. Many reviewers don't have that, and many reviewers aren't disciplined enough to skip edits on posts that aren't in their area of expertise.

Comment: On a side note, the comments suggest this answer is a bad idea, and possibly no longer functional.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara It worked fine for me, with the exeption of the problem that this fix solved

Comment: I probably would've approved that as well, also because I know a little git - having said that, the others probably saw that as a change to the code in the post, even if they do understand git. What they wanted to tell you was that it would be better to leave it as a comment, rather than edit since it changes the methodology in the answer.

Comment: Does GitHub no longer support ssh?

Answer (score 7):

Your comment looks like it is directed to the author of the post:

> use github https rather than ssh, for anonymous cloning (no ssh keys needed)

Your edit changes command syntax, but doesn't explain *why* in the *post*. Why do you switch to ssh from https? Without that information in the post, it looks like you are telling the author of the post that their way is incorrect - thus the "attempt to reply" rejection reason.

If you are making these types of changes, you need to make it clear what you are doing *and* be careful about touching code blocks on others' answers. If you are changing syntax, it can very easily appear that you are attempting to critique the code ("reply").

Comment: 100% agree. This is the primary reason I rejected the edit. I'm familiar with git, but typically, a code change like this should be a comment. This is one of those gray areas that pop up every once in a while, and I completely understand the reason for editing - it just works better as a comment.

Comment: @johnnyRose how should i have formatted/worded it then?

Comment: @KaidenPrince: as a comment, explaining the benefits of your changes.

Comment: @johnnyRose But I do not get rep for this. The whole reason I made the edit is to earn rep.

Comment: @KaidenPrince: sounds like you have the wrong motivation for this.